# (venv) prefix on bash terminal prompt in all directories

Tags: python, python3

I was initially very happy to see my terminal prompt prefixed with `(venv)` because I was *inside the folder where I am learning python*, and in that folder, I created a `./venv` folder to hold my virtual environment, which I seemed to have been able to activate.

Today I am horrified to discover that it now prefixes my prompt with `(venv)` literally everywhere else I go on my machine.

**Questions**

1. Is this the standard / expected behavior when u create a virtual env? **Why?** These other folders aren't even python projects.
2. how do I stop the madness / restrict python-env awareness to the relevant directories only?

`echo $PS1` gives:

```sh
(venv) \u@\h \[\]\w\[\] \[\]$git_branch\[\]$git_dirty\[\]$
```

and `grep -i PS1 ~/.*.rc* ~/.*bash* ~/.profile` gives:

```sh
/home/me/.bashrc:    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
/home/me/.bashrc:    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
/home/me/.bashrc:    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
/home/me/.bashrc:export PS1="\u@\h \[$txtgrn\]\w\[$txtrst\] \[$txtcyn\]\$git_branch\[$txtred\]\$git_dirty\[$txtrst\]\$ "
```

I do **not** recall editing any files like bash_profile  .bashrc .profile etc. either.

Thanks!

#### Update

I don't know if it helps, but it occurred to check my history for anything related to venv:

```
 1034  python3 -m venv venv
 1035  python3 -m venv ./venv
 1037  rm -rf venv/
 1040  python3 -m venv ./venv
 1042  ll venv/
 1043  ll venv/bin/
 1044  rm -rf venv
 1045  python3 -m venv --without-pip ./venv
 1046  ll venv/bin/
 1047  source ./venv/bin/activate
 1085  history grep "venv"
 1086  history | grep "venv"
```

Were any of those commands wrong?

Comment: What prompt?  Your operating system shell prompt, or some prompt from within a Python interpretor/program?  What happens if you run: "`echo $PS1`"?  How about "`echo $SHELL`"?  How about "`echo ls -la ~/.*.rc* ~/.*bash* /etc/*bash*`" and "`echo ls -la /etc/*rc*`"?  For any files reported, what happens if you just run "`ls -la`" on them?  (e.g., if /home/username/bash_profile is reported, what happens if you run "`ls -la /home/username/bash_profile`"?  How about "`grep -i PS1 ~/.*.rc* ~/.*bash* /etc/*bash* /etc/*rc*`"? (If the results of all this don't give you a clear answer, it might for us.)

Comment: (The best way to answer these questions may be to edit your existing question to add such info.  If you do, I suggest also fixing the spelling error in the Question/Topic (s/lt/lit/))

Comment: @TOOGAM thanks for the guidance! I updated the question. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command:

```
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

is what is updating your prompt (it's just a set of shell commands so feel free to `cat` it out to see specifically what it's doing) to show the name of the virtualenv, and it will remain on your prompt until you unload it with:

```
deactivate
```

The reason for this is that your environment (namely your PATH) still point to the python interpreter inside your virtualenv, regardless of what directory you find yourself in. You can see this by running something like:

```
which python3
```

Note that the `deactivate` command for your virtualenv will be in the same `bin/` directory as the interpreter.

Comment: omg... thank you!!!! I was going crazy!